# Confusing example from the Python re module

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re

From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> ...
>
> The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern
> occurrences to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer. If
> omitted or zero, all occurrences will be replaced. Empty matches for
> the pattern are replaced **only when not adjacent to a previous empty**
> **match**, so sub('x*', '-', 'abxd') returns '-a-b--d-'.

So `x*` should match

1. The empty string before a
2. The empty string between a and b
3. The empty string between b and x
4. The substring 'x'
5. The empty string between x and d
6. The empty string after d

Evidently (5) is not replaced, but I can't see why. If we removed the word "empty" from the bolded text above, I can see that (5) would not be replaced. But (5) is not adjacent to a previous empty match.

Comment: You can [view it in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1e88A3/1). It will replace 5. but not 3. because it's contained in  4.

Comment: Remember that the `'*'` operator is greedy -- it always grabs as many characters as it can.  Between "b" and "d", it is able to match a one "x", so it's not going to match an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... 3. The empty string between b and x ..."*

I don't believe there would be an empty string between *b* and *x*, since *x* matches.
The pattern is effectively, *"if x, 1 or more, or none"*.

For example, the only reason it's an empty space between *a* and *b* is because *b* is not an *x*.

```
             -----------------
characters   | a | b | x | d |
             -----------------
indices      0   1   2   3   4
```

| step | indices | substring | is x | current string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 to 1 | a | false | -abxd |
| 2 | 1 to 2 | b | false | -a-bxd |
| 3 | 2 to 3 | x | true | -a-b-d |
| 4 | 3 to 4 | d | false | -a-b--d |
| 5 | 4 |  | false | -a-b--d- |